# Arbitrary operator as a sum of Hermitian operators

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Probaly already asked.

> Show that an arbitrary operator $A$ can be written as $A=B+iC$, where $B$ and $C$ are Hermitian.

I think the matrix version is the sum of a symmetric and antisymmetry part, but I have no idea how to do it in the general case.

Comment: It is worth noting that the proposed duplicate Question contains a misstatement (one which is corrected in the Accepted Answer there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hint

> $$B=\frac{A+A^*}{2}\;\;\;\;\;C=\frac{A-A^*}{2i}$$

Comment: I want my entrance fee back.